# difference between "verb-ed" vs "to be + verb-ed"

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

what is difference of the below example:

> 1 When she **worried** she always rubbed her hands together
>   2 When she **is worried** she has always rubbed her hands together

Comment: Sentence 1 is ungrammatical: the verb "worried" is in (the?) past tense, while "rubs" is in the present tense. In sentence 2, "worried" is not a verb but an adjective: "She is **very worried**", "She is **more worried** now than ever".

Comment: @CopperKettle what is correct version for sentence 1?

Comment: It is now correct grammatically, but now your second sentence is not very grammatical: "she has" does not combine very good with "is worried" (present perfect vs. present simple). You might read up on basic verb forms.

Answer (score 5):

In the first sentence, "worried" is a verb.

In the second one however, "worried" is not a verb, it is an adjective. "be" is the English copula, which does a ton of functions. One of them is to identify nouns with adjectives or with other nouns.

e.g.

> He **is** dead.
>
> You **are** not a good basketball player.

Comment: are they have a difference in the meaning?

Comment: @Miro Just look up "worry" and "worried" in a dictionary...

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost I know `worry`, I meant in the context